# 15 minute timer between battery and main switch

Tags: circuit-design, 555, timer

[image]I am making a 15 minute timer between battery and main switch such that it doesn't run unnecessarily. I want such that if we press the switch in between it resets to 15 minutes again. I tried using 555 and CD4060 but can't reset the timer in between.

I have added the final circuit which I was able to make and it is working. However, further imporvement can be made using either res or transistor.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate your circuit? Have you considered an MCU instead?

Comment: I'm surprised that you went with a circuit that requires three different IC's instead of just one, but if it works for you, that's great.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no clock signal anywhere in the schematic.  You can use 4060 pins 9, 10, and 11 for this, and eliminate the need for a 555.
2. What is the current being drawn by the load?
3. NOTE:  All ICs require individual power supply decoupling capacitors across their power pins for proper operation.

Operating sequence:

1. On power-up, the system starts a 15 minute timing cycle.
2. After 15 minutes, the external load is powered.
3. The system sits in this mode continually until the reset button is pressed.
4. When the reset button is pressed, power to the load is cut off for 15 minutes.
5. If the reset button is pressed curing a 15 minute timing cycle, the timer restarts a 15 minute cycle.  The load stays off during the restart.

IF this is correct, here is a first pass at a schematic.

[image]

R1-C1 form a short reset pulse at power-up.  When power is removed, R5 discharges C1 in about 1 second so the circuit resets reliably when powered again.

R2-C2 are the main timing components for the oscillator.  R3 adds some adjustability to the 15 minute period.  As indicated in the schematic, T is the period of the oscillator, the time period of one cycle.  Each oscillator cycle clocks the 14-bit counter.  15 minutes is 900 seconds, so it is pretty straightforward to calculate the oscillator R and C.  For best operation, R4 should not be greater than 1 M for good noise immunity, and (R2+R3) should not be greater than 10% of R4. -ish.  Starting with a .47 uF cap, the timing resistance works out to around 106K, or 100K plus approx. 50% of the adjustment.

Q1 inverts the logic to drive Q2, the main power switch.  I threw in a normal p-channel power MOSFET, but for 5 V operation the circuit needs a logic-level part.  Or, Q2 can be replaced with a PNP bipolar transistor plus a base-current limiting resistor as shown in your schematic.

D2 is a heartbeat indicator to show that the timer is counting.

Pressing SW1 at any time resets the counter and restarts the 15 minute off period.

The CD4060 is an oscillator plus a 16,384-count divider.  That means that the last output, Q14, is low for the first 8192 counts, then high for another 8192 counts.  When the Q14 output goes high, it turns on the Q1 transistor.  This does two things - it turns on Q2 and it pulls D1 low.  This disrupts the timing oscillator circuit and the counter freezes, effectively latching off the clock.  It sits in that state until a Reset happens, either by cycling power or pressing SW1.  When reset, the Q14 output goes low and the cycle repeats.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain a lot. I have added res and cap for he pin 9, 10 and 11 and also improved the circuit. Using the flip flop I can reset the timer in between by additional diodes and inverter such that RST is high/low as per cycle requirement.

Comment: In what way did you improve the circuit?  Please add an updated schematic to your question we we can see things.

Answer (score 0):

In the unmodified circuit the reset sequence is:

- Press SW-PB.
- The base of Q7 is pulled low via R7 turning on Q7.
- Q7 pulls the RESET input of U2 high and the counter resets.

In the modified circuit:

- When SW-PB is released R7 pulls RESET high and preventing the counter from running. This is the opposite of what you require.